# TCP_USER_TIMEOUT socket option not honored

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I recently had a situation where my TCP client (sitting across WAN) experienced a WAN flap. The client kept sending data as the underlying TCP stack didn't report **ETIMEDOUT** error till it completed its **tcp_retries2** (default value is 16 on my system). With these default settings I see that I get a **connection timed out** error in about 15-16 mins. I wanted to reduce this timeout to 20 seconds.

Based on the definition of [TCP_USER_TIMEOUT](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html), I expected, if I set the socket option on the client side, it would timeout after the specified timeout.

```
int tcp_timeout = 20000;
auto status = setsockopt(mFd, IPPROTO_TCP , TCP_USER_TIMEOUT, &tcp_timeout, sizeof(tcp_timeout));
```

the socket above is set non-blocking.

I tried the following steps on my test VM:

1. Establish client-server connection. Client periodically (every 5 seconds) sends data to server
2. drop the packet on destination

   ```
   sudo iptables -A INPUT -s <dest_ip> -j DROP
   ```

   I also tried temporarily bringing the if down (via script)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   sudo ip link set eth0 down
   sleep 2
   sudo ip link set eth0 up
   ```
3. Observe that the SEND-Q keeps growing (used ss -p) for it.

I see that setting the socket option *TCP_USER_TIMEOUT is not making any difference* to the timeout period.

```
# uname -r
3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
```

Would really appreciate any help/pointers on this.

TIA

Comment: There is a lot of useful info [here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/when-tcp-sockets-refuse-to-die/).

Would be very helpful to see a network capture.

Comment: Using keepalive?  able to get a network capture? Fixing `IPPROTO_IP` to `IPPROTO_TCP` help?

Comment: Thanks @JimD. sorry for the delayed response, got busy in figuring this thing out. I could run this thing with some level of certainty with SO_KEEPALIVE. The behavior is quite subtle with keep alive as pointed out by your link. TCP_USER_TIMEOUT comes into play in the second ka-probe and where it just drops the connection when above timeout has elapsed. I'm still working on understanding its behavior on established connection with peer-end dead and its buffering on SEND-Q.

Comment: Ok, good luck with it.  You will be more likely to get help with your issue if you post code in your question that can reproduce your problem, or at least add a network capture.  Note that [SystemTap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap) can be very useful for understanding what is going on in the kernel, although to be most useful it is helpful to build a kernel with the relevant modules compiled without optimization.

Comment: @sanjayk79 did you figure out why? 
In my case, the code works on some Ubuntu servers but not work on other servers.
They have different kernels but they are similar 4.15.0